# How to interpret log Relative Hazard?

Tags: survival, cox-model, mortality

Let's have two groups, A and B, and let's assume that A is a reference in Cox model and B has two times higher hazard to die at a certain time point, Hazard Ratio = 2.

But what is log Relative Hazard and how to calculate it using the given example? Could you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name tells you what to do: the log relative hazard is the logarithm of the relative hazard, so in this example $\ln(2) \approx 0.69$.

Comment: One more final thing. log Relative Hazard = log Hazard Ratio? Two different names used for the same estimate?